# Mongoid : Array contains element or is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I want to make a request which returns elements from my collection if a string is in an array or if the array is empty. I tried the following:

```
Collection.all_of(or: [{ assets: my_asset }, { assets: [] } ])
```

But this doesn't work.

This works but not for the empty arrays:

```
Collection.where(assets: my_asset)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer using

```
Collection.where(:assets.in => [[], my_asset])
```

Answer (score 2):

try using any_of

```
Collection.any_of({ assets: my_asset }, { assets: [] })
```